# how javascript add property to an object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was reading javascript questions where i found this piece of code

```
var a={},
    b={key:'b'},
    c={key:'c'};

a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]);      // o/p - 456
```

can anybody make me understand this code why and how it is printing **456**?

And I think we can use **dot** i.e `a.b = 123` and **string** `a['b'] = 123` approach to add property to an object.

Comment: `b` is an object, when used as key converted to string as `[object Object]`, `c` is again an object which will be converted to string when used as key. This will overwrite the previous value, thus 456.

Comment: When using dot notation and bracket notation with string, you're actually adding `b` property on the object.

Answer (score 3):

Both `b` and `c` resolve to the same string (`[object Object]`). Hence you are overwriting the same key.

> And I think we can use dot i.e a.b = 123 and string a['b'] = 123
>   approach to add property to an object.

Yes you can, but `a['b']` is very different from `a[b]`. The first one resolves to a key with a string value just as it shows (`'b'`), where as the other one will depend on the stringified value of the variable `b` (in this case is `[object Object]`).

Answer (score 0):

For really using the content of the object, you may use the [stringified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) version.

```js
var a = {},
    b = { key: 'b' },
    c = { key: 'c' };

a[JSON.stringify(b)] = 123;
a[JSON.stringify(c)] = 456;

console.log(a[JSON.stringify(b)]);
```